# AWS ASP.NET Error: provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server. Server running, allows remote connection, ports open

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, amazon-web-services, .net-core

I am deploying a demo on AWS EC2 Instances.

I have a Win Server 2022 instance running SQL Server (Launched from the AWS AMI that pre-includes SQL Server). And a Amazon Linux instance hosting the ASP.NET application, running .NET SDK 6.0, .NET runtime 6.0 and ASP runtime 6.0. (**Noteworthy**: I had difficulties getting .NET installed. Ultimately I had to download the archives from Microsoft, `scp` them to the Linux instance, then decompress them to `/usr/local` and set my PATH to include it. This all seemed to have worked, my app runs but does not connect to the database.)

I am running a Minimal API on the ASP.NET application. When I browse to an endpoint, it spins for about 5 seconds and returns this error:

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6.1",
  "title": "An error occurred while processing your request.",
  "status": 500,
  "detail": "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing \
    a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify \
    that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote \
    connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"
}
```

Previous iterations of the application worked on local installs on my dev machine.

**Environment and troubleshooting steps**

*I'll try to edit the post if I can to add images again when allowed*

The connection String is supplied in an `appsettings.json` file in the root of the application folder:

```
[ec2-user@[aws-linux-host] [appfolder]]$ ls -al
total 5584
drwxr-xr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user    4096 Jan 10 15:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root     root          43 Jan  8 20:07 ..
...
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user     302 Jan 10 15:53 appsettings.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user  142840 Jan 10 15:45 [webapp-name]
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user  551424 Jan 10 15:45 [webapp-name].dll
...
```

`appsettings.json` contents:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Data Source=[ip-of-win-server];Initial Catalog=[DBNAME];User ID=[sql-server-login];Password=[sql-server-login-password]"
  }
}
```

- MSSQLSERVER is running on the Win Server

```
> Get-Service MSSQLSERVER

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  MSSQLSERVER        SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)
```

- I am connecting using an IP Address in the Connection String and the TCP/IP connection is enabled in SQL Server Configuration Manager

[SQL Server Configuration Manager]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZfMT.png)

- The Server is configured to accept remote connections

[Server Properties]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuRnK.png)

- The SQL Server login used in the Connection String is granted permission to connect

[Login Permissions]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BHDS.png)

- The Firewall is open on the Win Server for TCP/1433 and TCP/1434

```
> Get-NetFirewallPortFilter -All | ? {$_.LocalPort -In (1433,1434)} | FT

Protocol LocalPort RemotePort IcmpType DynamicTarget
-------- --------- ---------- -------- -------------
TCP      1433      Any        Any      Any
TCP      1433      Any        Any      Any
TCP      1434      Any        Any      Any
TCP      1434      Any        Any      Any
```

- The security group for the EC2 instance has an inbound rule to allow 1433 from the subnet of the webapp host (and they're both in the same subnet, so routing is not an issue)

[EC2 Security Group on Win Server]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zLT1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question

The issue was the Security Group had an inbound rule for the wrong subnet. IPs for the two hosts ended in .125 and .126, I needed to allow from .112/28.